# Can't publish a message successfully on RabbitMQ server with AMQP-CPP

Tags: c++, windows, rabbitmq, console-application, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to make a simple console application on windows. I have installed AMQP-CPP and included the library on my Visual Studio project. My task is to create the simple communication with the rabbitmq server.

The main function is:

```
#include <amqpcpp.h>
#include "rabbitmqModels.h"

int main(){

    string msg = "hello world";
    string queueName = "message_queue";
    string exchangeName = "myexchange";
    string routingKey = "hello";

    Address address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672");
    MyConnectionHandler myHandler;
    Connection connection(&myHandler, address);
    Channel channel(&connection);

    channel.declareQueue(queueName);
    channel.declareExchange(exchangeName, direct).onSuccess([]();
    channel.bindQueue(exchangeName, queueName, routingKey);
    channel.publish(exchangeName, routingKey, msg, msg.size());

    return 0;
}
```

where rabbitmqModels.h code is:

```
using namespace AMQP;
class MyConnectionHandler : public ConnectionHandler
{
private:
    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library every time it has data
     *  available that should be sent to RabbitMQ.
     *  @param  connection  pointer to the main connection object
     *  @param  data        memory buffer with the data that should be sent to RabbitMQ
     *  @param  size        size of the buffer
     */
    virtual void onData(Connection* connection, const char* data, size_t size)
    {
        // @todo
        //  Add your own implementation, for example by doing a call to the
        //  send() system call. But be aware that the send() call may not
        //  send all data at once, so you also need to take care of buffering
        //  the bytes that could not immediately be sent, and try to send
        //  them again when the socket becomes writable again
    }

    virtual void onReady(Connection* connection) override
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by creating a channel
        //  instance, and start publishing or consuming
        std::cout << "Connection is established...\n";

    }

    virtual void onError(Connection* connection, const char* message)
    {
        // report error
        std::cout << "Connection Error: " << message << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void onClosed(Connection* connection)
    {
        std::cout << "closed" << std::endl;

    }

    virtual void onConnected(Connection* connection)
    {
        std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The code builds without errors. Note that my rabbitmq server runs on localhost:15672 and I have defined both the queue and the exchange/routing key.

The thing is that I cannot see any message coming to my defined queue on the server.
Do I have to use only TCPHandler? I can't find any implementation of TCPHandler for windows.
Can you please provide any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information beyond the simple typo mentioned below in an answer. There could be dozens of reasons why a published message doesn't make it to the queue. Can you please try to do more troubleshooting to the point at which you have a specific error?

Answer (score 1):

Port `15672` is the default `HTTP` port for the management web interface and REST API. You want to use the `AMQP` port which is `5672`.

Change your code to this:

```
Address address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");
```

Please note that the [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html) is very thorough. Please take the time to read it and complete one of the language-specific tutorials.

Comment: thanks for the info! The RabbitMq  documentation is truly very informative. But still, the change on port number didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You have an environment configuration error, then. `5672` is the default. Either you have changed that, or there is a firewall blocking the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your application completes execution before the channel is even ready. Try waiting for `channel.onReady()` before performing any channel operations. To do this you will need an event loop library like libev, libevent or libuv.

main

```
#include <amqpcpp.h>
#include "rabbitmqModels.h"
#include <amqpcpp/libev.h>
#include <ev.h>

int main()
{

    string msg = "hello world";
    string queueName = "message_queue";
    string exchangeName = "myexchange";
    string routingKey = "hello";

    // Event loop
    auto *loop = EV_DEFAULT;

    Address address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");
    MyLibEvHandler myHandler(loop);
    Connection connection(&myHandler, address);
    Channel channel(&connection);

    channel.onReady([&channel]() {
        channel.declareQueue(queueName);
        channel.declareExchange(exchangeName, direct).onSuccess([]();
        channel.bindQueue(exchangeName, queueName, routingKey);
        channel.publish(exchangeName, routingKey, msg, msg.size());
    });

    // Run loop
    ev_run(loop, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

`MyLibEvHandler` must inherit `LibEvHandler`

There are good examples here (although they are using TCP): https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/tree/master/examples